# How to automatically edit html tables with perl?

Tags: html, perl, html-table

I have a large number of big html tables (around 1000) where certain cells or lines needs to be edited.. the editing itself is same for all the required tables so it can be easily automated. So I was looking for a way to do it with perl. I found html::TableExtract is very useful to get the data out of table but I can't find a way to edit them and put them back into html. If someone help me with a little example code I will be grateful.

edit : The files I am trying to parse are like  http://pastehtml.com/view/bsyxg5y2t.html
I need to edit some cell or delete entire rows according to the value of the first column.

I tried to use HTML::TableExtract but now stuck with an error called:

> "Can't bless non-reference value at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/HTML/ElementTable .pm line 431."

The code is as follows

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract 'tree'; 
use YAML;
print "starting \n";
my @headers = (qw(mRNA Chromosome));
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new(slice_columns=> 1,
                              keep_html => 0,
              headers => \@headers );
$te->parse_file('hsa-let-7a-2-3p-3.html');
foreach my $ts ($te->tables) {
  print "======= Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), ") =======\n";
  print join("\t", @headers), "\n";

  foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
    print join(',', @$row), "\n";
  }
}
```

Note : Its working if i change it to,
    use HTML::TableExtract
to change a cell i tried this but encountered the same error when using tree

```
$table_tree = $ts->tree;
$table_tree->cell(2,2)->replace_content('change here');
$table_html = $table_tree->as_HTML;
$table_text = $table_tree->as_text;
$document_tree = $te->tree;
$document_html = $document_tree->as_HTML;
print $document_html;
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Why can't you store your data in a proper format? E.g. in a SQL database.

Comment: the problem is the tables are generated by a prediction algorithm and now i need an extra layer of filter on those tables without changing the algorithm.. hope i make myself clear.

Comment: It becomes an interesting question if we stipulate that nothing but the specified table cell may be modified (e.g: HTML source formatting preserved). I'd try to take a SAX-like parsing approach to visit and edit the appropriate node, and pass the rest back out unmolested.

Comment: Could you start to "use strict;" and "use warnings"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the content and use `$table->tree->as_HTML` afterwards?

Comment: That would work fine (unless the formatting of the HTML source must be preserved).

Comment: @weismat I was trying to do that following the example of html::tableExtract but coudnt do it. I am new to perl. Can you give me a small example and explain it please.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I need the format of html preserved only need to removed some rows according to my criteria.

Comment: @weismat I have updated the code and uploaded a sample html file also, I need to change or delete the rows according to some criteria on first colomn. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You would use $te->tree->as_HTML.

Comment: @weismat I tried it with the following code but also encountered the same error :(